# Is PACT suitable for testing for JWT with various claims?

Tags: jwt, pact, contract

Currently I am involved in a cluster of micro-services. Some of these micro-services are generating JWT with various claims (with/without expiration date, not before time etc.) My question is PACT suitable for JWT validation or not? Like generated JWT for microservice A to be valid and accepted by generated JWT for microservice B.

- didn't found nothing clear on the internet regarding JWT

XoXo

Comment: Pact allows you to define contracts which stipulate that there should a `Authorization` header with a JWT token but it doesn't go into specifying the content of the token as far as I know.

Comment: This is exactly my supposition too. Like I know to add validation for JWT to be present/not null etc...but how to make sure that the received JWT is a valid one is not clear how to

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. If JWT from the consumer side affects provider/server response then you can test it. Consider JWT just as an additional *object* just encoded. So, whenever it's changed - it's a new input data.

For example, you know that a provider/server returns 403 in case of missing permission in the claim - you can write this exact contract test in Pact.